# JavaScript find in json array match key

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object that changes as it is appended with other objects throughout my application.
I have created a JavaScript function which behaves like **indexOf** but for a JSON array.
It looks like this:

```
// Find via slug
self.findSlug = function (array, slug) {

    // Counter
    var i = array.length;

    // While i
    while (i--) {

        // If we find our slug, break the loop
        if (array[i].slug === slug)
            break;
    }

    // Return our counter
    return i;
}
```

this works fine if the JSON object has a key called "slug". Now I would like to make it abiguous. i.e. something like:

```
if (array[i]["key-name"] === slug) break;
```

Here is an example of an array:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Hoody",
        "price": 10,
        "designable": true,
        "configurable": true,
        "slug": "hoody",
        "fabric": "980506857489564534",
        "font": "city-bold",
        "fabrics": [

        ]
    }
]
```

but that doesn't appear to work. Can someone suggest a way of doing this?

Cheers,
/r3plica

Comment: Use `array[i][slug]` instead of `array[i].slug`

Comment: Can you give a sample array which you are testing with? This should work if your array items are objects

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

var array =   {
    1:{"title": "Hoody",        "price": 10,"designable": true,"configurable": true,"slug": "hoody", "fabric": "980506857489564534",
        "font": "city-bold", "fabrics": [     ] },
   2:{"title": "Hoody2",        "price": 20,"designable": true,"configurable": true,"slug": "hoody2", "fabric": "980506857489564534",
        "font": "city-bold", "fabrics": [     ] }
}

```
for (key in array){
        for (subkey in array[key])  {
            if(subkey=="slug"){
                 //do something
            }
        }
}
```